# Nice way to cover vent and drain after removing washer dryer

Tags: bathroom, drain, vent

We have moved out washer and dryer upstair. But the basement bathroom still has all the vent and drain holes.

What is the best way to cover or make things look nice (beside drywall over)?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

I am thinking of these options:

1. Wrap aluminum foil around the air vent
2. Frame it out a bit and put 3-gang wall plate https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-3-Gang-No-Device-Blank-Wallplate-Standard-Size-302-Stainless-Steel-Box-Mount-Stainless-Steel-84033-40/301693157

Comment: Do you want to leave the tubing Undamaged for possible future use?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it. We want to keep options.